# Did Data die at the end of Star Trek:Nemesis?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

Data sacrificed himself at the end of Star Trek:Nemesis and the ship blew up but his memories were stored in B4 which some say caused Data to actually be living in B4 now. But there is an episode where if he were disassembled **"Measure of Man"** that he would lose the product of his memories that made him sentient person. So did Data die or is Data still alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.    (The point is for it to be ambiguous.)